# read the data from file (precision to 15 decimal places) in C

Tags: c, c++11, cygwin

My text file which needs to be read is in following format (data.dat) -

0.001505882352941
   34.900000000000018
   121.800000000000010

i want to assign the following values to given buffer which is of type float and constraint is that i cannot change the data type of buffer

```
 fprintf(file_ptr, "%f", &buffer);
```

i tried other methods also

```
double val;  
fprintf(file_ptr,"%lf", &val);
buffer = (float *) val;
```

but i am not getting proper values
i am running this program on cygwin window

values after decimal is always constant in number till 15 places

Comment: To be a bit nit-picky. Are these values really 20+ digits of precision? They look like 34.9 and 121.8 plus some tiny artefacts from previous floating-point calculations.

Comment: no till 15 places

Comment: And do you actually have/need that much precision? Bear in mind that 15 significant digits is very nearly enough to represent the circumference of the solar system (~1.43e13m) to the nearest centimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which is of type float and constraint is that i cannot change the data type of buffer

Then you've got a problem.

> values after decimal is always constant in number till 15 places

That's about the number of significant digits a double precision float can hold. There are 53 bits available for the mantissa in a IEEE 754 double precision floating point value. That gives you log10(2^53) = 15.95 decimal digits of precision (round that down to 15). That's what it can hold.

If you need higher precision you must use a different data type possibly combined with using a multiprecision math library.

Comment: its okay till 15 places to read but i am not getting the value as mentioned in file.

Comment: @RohanG: Something, something roundoff error… Floating point can represent only a (small) subset of rational numbers with absolute precision. For everything outside that set you only get an approximate value. That's the deal you have to agree to when using floating point.